# What does "へ?" mean

Tags: translation, usage, questions

I've searched around and I've only found the usage of へ as being a particle meaning "in the direction of..." I'm not sure what it means as an interjectional question.

Context:

```
Girl: ねえ
      三島さんが
      具合悪いみたいなの
      保健室連れていくね
Mishima: へ?
Girl: うんわかったー
      先生にいっておくね
```

Since the particle へ deals with direction, would the question be something like "This way?" or "In this direction?"

Comment: Just a note... the English translation you had doesn't match the Japanese at all. It would be something like: Girl 1 (to Girl 2 not Mishima-san): Mishima-san seems(みたい) not to be feeling well.(imagined full stop after なの) I'll take her to the nurse's office, OK? / Mishima (who is not sick): へ？ / Girl 2: Okay, I got it. I'll let the teacher know.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Like you figured, I had thought she was talking to Mishima. Anyway, thanks for the help. I know I'm learning Japanese on hard stuff, but I'm still having fun.

Answer (score 6):

You would need a better dictionary than that.  I would recommend a good monolingual one to anyone who is serious about his Japanese study.

The only possible answer would be that it is a dramatized pronunciation of the interjection え/えっ = "What?", which would mean that Mishima is NOT really sick.  If Mishima were actually sick, this へ？ would make no sense.

You might also want to remember that we rarely, if ever, utter a particle all by itself like that.